# how to use chrome extension with Tosca?

Tags: automation, tosca

I am not able to use Tosca extension for Chrome. As soon as i install the extension and try to run the scan using Tosca, it displays the below message

[image]

and as I press the Yes button it displays the following error

[image]

not able to resolve the issue. Also the extension disappears from the browser and I am forced to install it again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would urge you to get in contact with Tricentis Support (https://support.tricentis.com/).
I expect they will be able to help you better than this community in that particular case.

Comment: yes it seems there is not much about Tosca outside the tricentis community as of now

Comment: I would not put it like that... if you have specific questions chances are you will find answers without Tricentis Support.
If you have an exception like above it might be easier to contact support to get some engineers look at it and resolve it quickly.

Comment: Interestingly, there is a link on the official Tricentis website to...  Here.  I mean Stackoverflow.  with the [Tosca] tag pre-filled in.  And as we know, Tosca is VERY lightly covered here so far... heh

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by updating the chrome to latest version. Its working fine now after updating the browser and restarting

Comment: Cool - glad you where able to resolve it!
The system requirements in Tosca's manual list all supported browsers + versions by the way: https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=10.3.0&url=systemanforderungen/systemrequirements.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the keyword was changed, use this one "Tricentis Automation Extension for Chrome"
[Extension for Chromme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVu8x.png)

Answer (score -3):

Install the Tosca Automation Extension for Chrome. You could navigate to chrome://extensions/ and download and install the extension from her. For the exact name, you can refer to the image below.

[image]